# Sampling data from a large array

Tags: java, arrays, sampling

Basically I have a very large array of objects and I need to remove 10% of the least fit objects.

Each object has a fitness variable (a double) associated with it. I dont have a number which determines whether or not an object is fit, I just want the least fit of the bunch.

What is the best way of retrieving (sampling) the least fit objects?

One way could be randomly select lets way 20%, sort the data, then remove 10%. But I think this is not a very smart way of doing it.

The other way it to keep the array sorted at all times then remove the first 10%. But I dont think this is very good because you will have to always keep sorting the array whilst inserting/updating which is a big overhead..

Comment: Why don't you try a [Priority Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) that orders by fitness? Then just call `remove()` until you've cleared your 10%?

Comment: Thanks I didnt know about Priority Queues, let me try it out

Comment: @thegrinner I realised that I cannot use a priority Queue because I need to be able to retrieve elements using their indexed position. Is there any other datastructure I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let k be `yourCollection.length() * 0.1` and `n = yourCollection.length()`.

Find the k-th smallest element (QuickSelect or Median of 5), where the key is your fitness. Let's call it `p`. This can be done in `O(n)`.

Then traverse through the collection and remove all the items with fitness less than p.fitness. We've got an `O(n)` solution.

Or, you can create a heap in `O(n)` with `key=fitness` and remove `k` elements from it in `O(k * log(n))`.

Comment: Thank you. I'm a little confused, could you please go into more detail?  Is it a good idea to be using fitness as the key? because It will be constantly updated.

Comment: @RegUser : Can you please provide more information about the usage? Assuming that the fitness can be calculated in constant time, the first solution runs in ```O(n)``` even for multiple removals together (```"O(n) + 9/10 O(n) + 81/100 O(n)" ... ~ O(n)```, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression). If you want a faster single removal, you can maintain a tree of the records and store the sizes of the subtrees, which allows you to find your set in ```O(k + log n)```. But this will require additional maintenance of the tree and it'll get slow if the fitness is updated often.

Comment: Using a modified genetic algorithm to solve TSP. After each generation I want to remove 10% of the worst individuals without iterating over the whole population and with very little computational power - The most important thing is that it is efficient.

Comment: If your program has a part that does something like ```loop(update all the fitnesses, then remove the worst 10%)```, I'd stick to the first solution. Because maintaining a smart structure would be more costy than the straightforward approach. Note that if you don't mind about not having exactly 10% in case of some fitnesses being the same, you don't need to traverse your array again and you're fine with the QuickSelect result.

Comment: Generally, there's no better solution. When you update your fitnesses, you change the input completely. If we were able to pick the lowest 10% in sub-linear time, we could also sort (using only comparisons) faster than ```O(n log m)```. Which would be great, unfortunately it's proven impossible.